# How to remove dependencies that are not used?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

I added many dependencies in `build.gradle` ago and nowadays I don't remember which of them are not being used anymore.

How can I find out all the redundant dependencies with only one step? It's take me much time to delete one and re-compile and then repeat delete.

Comment: Delete one and re-compile.

Comment: The better solution is creating Unit test cases and UI test cases and running code coverage.check the report and remove the dependencies which are not called either.

Answer (score 0):

I simply delete one by one and build again.

Answer (score 0):

delete dependencies you think is redundant and clean project...if any of them is NOT redundant gives you an error message and you could find out that is necessary...

Answer (score 0):

A gradle plug-in called `gradle-dependency-analyze` can do that for you:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'ca.cutterslade.gradle:gradle-dependency-analyze:1.1.0'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
// Dependency analysis plugin must be applied after the java plugin.
apply plugin: 'ca.cutterslade.analyze'
```

See [here](https://github.com/wfhartford/gradle-dependency-analyze) for further details.

Comment: Thanks, but how to use? I add the snippet in `guild.gradle`(Project level, not module level) and then build, but nothing happen.

Comment: I use `gradlew analyzeDependencies` in the root directory of my android project, and it show something like :processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:analyzeTestClassesDependencies
:analyzeDependencies

Comment: and then BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 16.122 secs

Comment: so what should I do now

Comment: seems like you don't have unused dependencies, add one you really don't need and see the result